# Prevent EXC_BAD_ACCESS during backgrounding for long running processes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my application, I have a series of long running processes. Sometimes, when the app gets backgrounded, one of these processes will return and try to notify other objects (which have been released) that it has completed, causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Something like:

```
[process runForALongTimeWithCompletion:^(){
  [possiblyReleasedObject heyTheProcessFinished];
}];
```

How can I check if `possiblyReleasedObject` has been released? Or, more precisely in my case, how do I check if it is dereference-able, such that referring to it won't cause a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Comment: simply use a weak reference for `possiblyReleasedObject` it will become `nil` when the last strong reference to the object is gone. it is perfectly ok to send a message to `nil` in Obj-C

Comment: either this, or make sure the object doesn't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to (safely) check if a pointer to an object points to a valid memory location in Objective-C. You'll need to structure your program such that objects holding a pointer to `possiblyReleasedObject` retain it so that it doesn't get inadvertently released.

When an object holding a pointer to `possiblyReleasedObject` no longer needs it, it's generally good practice to set the pointer to `nil` after calling `release` in order to avoid accidentally dereferencing a bad pointer.

Comment: this is false. Objective-c has Automatic Reference Counting, and alongside that, weak pointers which are set to `nil` when the object the reference is deallocated. no need to `retain` or `release` anything in modern objective-c

Comment: @BradAllred: no, its true. if it crashes because of a dangling pointer, the solution is not to check if the pointer is still alive, because that's not possible. How can you check if 0x92837260 points to a valid address?

Comment: @Michael learn what a weak pointer is. they become _nil_ when the object they point to is destroyed; they don't dangle. Your advice became antiquated with ARC.

Comment: @BradAllred : dude, I know what a weak pointer is. I even read the objc runtime source. I understand what you are saying. I know that weak pointers can solve the problem of the OP. The answer is still correct though. You have to learn to read properly!

Comment: @BradAllred weak pointers become nil when the pointee deallocates. They sidestep the problem of trying to check if a pointer is alive. There still is no way to check if a given pointer address like 0x82715150 is valid or not.

Comment: this answer is insufficient for modern Objective-C. I _did_ read it and I saw this quote: "There is no way to (safely) check if a pointer to an object points to a valid memory location in Objective-C."  but weak pointers a meant for exactly this. You also mention `retain` and `release` you can't even do those things with ARC.

Comment: @BradAllred why don't you post your own answer?

Comment: @BradAllred sure, the answer can be improved by adding weak pointers. But that doesn't make it wrong, does it?

Comment: @BradAllred even under ARC objects are retained and released. Instead of -retain and -release ARC uses objc_retain and objc_release. Ita still reference counting

Comment: @Michael You are right that the answer is not incorrect. My complaint is that it feels _incomplete_ without mention of ARC and it's less likely to help others. OP asked about checking a previously good pointer to a transient object, not about inferring validity of an arbitrary address. ARC internals, `objc_retain`, semantics of raw pointers all make for a fun discussion, but it's not likely to help people that land here. Its a fair point that I can write my own answer, but OP accepted this and there are many extremely well written questions and answers regarding ARC and similar issues to this.

Comment: @BradAllred: that's a fair point, I just upvoted your comment btw. I was in a situation once where an ios app did crash occasionally, and a co-worker asked me if there is a way to check if a pointer address is valid. And she didn't want to know about weak pointers but really about checking pointer addresses. So I thought "well, this is a reasonable question then". I said that this is not possible. (Maybe it is possible with signal handling, but the idea of doing this is horrifying.) ...

Comment: @BradAllred: On the other hand, I still think that the answer is okay though, and maybe this is where we disagree. But I understand your point and I think it is reasonable! If you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in your app, there is a logic error in your design or a race condition (or data race or dealloc race (these categories are not mutually exclusive)). You should find the error, improve your understanding of the program and fix the program then. I rarely used weak pointers to check if an object is alive. I use them e.g. for delegate protocols, or for breaking retain cycles.

Comment: @BradAllred: and if I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in an app, I pause for a moment and try to understand the problem and fix that. Maybe the pointer should be retained instead? Maybe there is an over-releasee somewhere? (This can even happen with ARC, e.g. when you are using NSInvocation in a wrong way.) All these issues get hidden if you just put a "weak pointer duck tape" on the issue. Weak pointers also have other problems: if you try to get a weak pointer of an object that is currently deallocating, you get a crash (a hardware trap, not an exception).